# Android Studio - Failed to resolve: com.android.support libraries

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-manager

I got 2 gradle errors when compiling.

*Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.1*

*Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1*

I try to install the repositories and it starts to install v14 support libraries and after it finishes and sync's it displays the same error again. Also tried cleaning and rebuilding the project.

**Android studio version: 1.2.1.1**

**Build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.piserve.geejo.mskv4"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'org.lucasr.dspec:dspec:0.1.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.1'
}
```

**SDK Manager Screenshot**

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add these to your `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Am sorry, I had added that too. Missed to copy it while pasting it here. I have now edited the code in the first post. Getting the same error still.

Answer (score 2):

There is no published `22.0.1` version of those artifacts. Use a version that has been published, like `22.1.1`.

Comment: You  mean the support libraries?

Comment: @George: Yes. Use `'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'` and `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'`, as shown in Bojan's answer.

Comment: Ok I did that , and after cleaning and rebuilding the project I get this error: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
         file:/home/droidspace/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
     Required by:
         MSKv4:app:unspecified[jar also]

Comment: @George: Then your Android Repository in the SDK Manager is not up to date. That's down in the Extras branch of the tree, towards the bottom of the SDK Manager contents.

Answer (score 0):

Also the older versions seems no longer to be available after new version have been released. I even cannot get hold of the 22.1.1 support library any longer.

Comment: This is better-suited as a comment.

Comment: @msanford if they let me write comments I would ;)

Comment: Ah. It came up in the Triage Review queue. I guess that's something I could bring up in Meta.

Comment: @msanford It seems like I can only comment on my own answers.... so another answer seems the only way to contribute anything to a question I havent answered yet... Not that I have to understand this logic, do I?

Comment: Yeah, there are some spam-busting restrictions against that; please disregard for the time being :)